# war file of web service

Tags: web-services, web, client, war

I am developing a web service using Exlipse ( Java EE - JUNO- ), Tomcat, and CXF.

I have problem because I am not sure how I can export the war file; Specially two folders have been created. one for the service and the other for the client.

can anybody please explain to me how I can export and deploy the war file correctly.

thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Project Explorer, you can right click on your project name → export → WAR File

A WAR File is for a Web App. For the second project (client), you should export is as a JAR file. You can select the option "Export source files".

You can deploy the WAR file on a web application server like Apache Tomcat. I don't know exactly how to but it's simple, you can search for it.

Comment: thanks a lot .. but what I should do when I export the jar file of client .. shall I attach it with war file of service ?